# Unable to create venv in directory venv

Tags: python, python-2.7, stable-diffusion

I open the webui-user.bat file from the stable-diffusion-webui, artificial intelligence that creates art, but cmd opens and says:

```
Creating venv in directory venv using python "C:\Python27\python.exe"
Unable to create venv in directory venv

exit code: 1

stderr:
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named venv

Launch unsuccesful. Exiting.
Press a key to continue...
```

I have the version 2.7.15 of Python, I don't know if the stable diffusion supports that version really. The thing is that after reading on another site that I could try typing commands such as py -m pip install --user virtualenv, I type it, but I always get a syntaxerror:

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
File "<stdin>", line 1
py -m pip install --user virtualenv

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve this issue? Anyone who can help me, please?

Comment: `py` is a non-standard alias for `python`. Try with `python` instead. However, AFAIK, `pip` started being included into Python distribution since 3.4 (before that it was installed separately); `venv` is available from 3.3 (before that, a separate `virtualenv` package served this purpose). I haven't checked, but I would be rather surprised if Stable Diffusion even worked on 2.7 (which reached end-of-life two years ago). tl;dr: Use a non-ancient Python.

Comment: The problem is that the new version that is supposed to support stable diffussion is not able to install on my computer, with a Windows 7 operating system and with Windows Update disabled at the time of installation and non-functional, so I cannot upgrade to a newer operating system except by erasing my entire hard drive or something.

Comment: I have not tried, but [Python Windows download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) seems to indicate that "Python 3.8.10 - May 3, 2021" should be able to be installed on Win7.

Comment: Yes, I know, I mean that when I open the setup program it tells me that the installation cannot be done, that I need the service pack or some other problem, when I go to install the service pack it says that I already have one of the files installed. So that's why I'm telling you, that on my computer I can't install that version.

Comment: So downloading a newer version is not the solution for me, since the Python installer won't let me do it